# C# Ожидание выполнения консольного приложения

Tags: c#

Добрый день!

Есть консольное приложение: приложение принимает команды, подключается к серверу, выполняет команды и возвращает их результат в консольный вывод.

Задача- перехватывать вывод, ожидая результат выполнения команды.

После чего возвращать этот результат.

Приложение закрывать нельзя. (реконнект очень долгий)

По этому перехватывать вывод нужно на открытом приложении.(принципиальный момент)

- метод-конструктор `AppWorker` создает экземпляр процесса, подключается
  к процессу и передает команду коннекта.
- все команды в приложение передаются через `imputCommand`,
- перехватываются эвентом     `process_OutputDataReceived`,
- пишутся в `outputResult`,
- ожидание работы    приложения выполняется методом `WaitForEnd`,
- приложение не возвращается никакие статусы и само не закрывается.

Команда считается выполненной если в выводе есть слова `" completed"` `"Failed"`,

тогда эвент проставляет флаг
`workFlag = false` и ожидание прерывается, результат возвращается.

Как мне корректно реализовать `WaitForEnd`?

Если команда выполняется слишком долго- результат не возвращается.

После возврата результата `WaitForEnd` все равно продолжает работать.

`Process.WaitForExit()` - длится вечность, и не является решением проблемы

```
static StringBuilder _outputResult = new StringBuilder();
static StreamWriter _imputCommand;
static Process process;
internal AppWorker(string appPath, string command)
{
    process = new Process()
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(appPath)
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
        }
    };
    process.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;
    process.Start();

    _imputCommand = process.StandardInput;
    _imputCommand.WriteLine(command);
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    _outputResult.Clear();
}

private static bool _workFlag = true;

private async Task<string> WaitForEnd()
{
    while (_workFlag)
    {
       await Task.Delay(300);
    }
    return _outputResult.ToString();
}

internal string ExecuteCommand(string command)
{
    Console.WriteLine(command);
    _outputResult.Clear();
    _workFlag = true;
    _imputCommand.WriteLine(command);
    var result = WaitForEnd().Result;
    _workFlag = false;
    return result;
}
private readonly  string _applicationName = "servAdapter>";
private  void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
    {
        if (e.Data.Contains(" completed") || e.Data.Contains("Failed"))
        {

            if (e.Data.Contains(_applicationName))
                _outputResult.AppendLine(e.Data.Substring(e.Data.IndexOf(_applicationName) + _applicationName.Length));
            else
                _outputResult.AppendLine(e.Data);

            _workFlag = false;
        }
        else 
        {
            if (e.Data.Contains(_applicationName))
                _outputResult.AppendLine(e.Data.Substring(e.Data.IndexOf(_applicationName) + _applicationName.Length));
            else
                _outputResult.AppendLine(e.Data);
        }
    }
}
 public void Dispose()
 {       
     process.Close();
     _outputResult.Clear();
     _imputCommand.Dispose();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет, надеюсь вопрос ещё актуален.

Исходя из кода, твоё приложение сервер на самом деле является **дочерним процессом**. Что-бы процесс родитель мог читать в тот момент когда дочерний процесс ожидает ввод новых данных, необходимо реализовать собственный механизм получения данных базирующися на более "низкоуровневневых" методах **Read** или **ReadBuffer**. Более высокоуровневые - **ReadToEnd** или **ReadLine**  не увидев в конце перевода каретки ожидают дальнейшего отображения данных.

С учётом того что переоткрытие дочернего процесса длится какое-то время имеет смысл сделать ожидание его открытия асинхронным.

Исходя из этих размышлений можно сделать что-то по типу такого:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var worker = new AppWorker())
            {
                string str;
                // interactive wait for starting child process
                Console.Write("Process initializing");
                var childProcessPath = "C:\\repos\\test\\run\\bin\\Debug\\run.exe";
                var awaiter = worker.Start(childProcessPath) 
                    .GetAwaiter();
                while (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
                {
                    Console.Write('.');
                    Task.Delay(10).Wait();
                }
                // if our starting child process throw the exception wait it here
                awaiter.GetResult();

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write(":> ");
                while ((str = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(":< {0}", worker.Execute(str).Result);
                    Console.Write(":> ");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class AppWorker : IDisposable
    {
        private Process _process;

        public async Task Start(string appPath)
        {
            if (_process != null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Child process has been started");

            _process = new Process();
            _process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            _process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            _process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            _process.StartInfo.FileName = appPath;
            // As your application starting takes some time do it asynchronously
            await Task.Run(() => { 
                if (!_process.Start())
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Couldn't start child process");
            });
        }

        public async Task<string> Execute(string command)
        {
            const int bufferSize = 256;
            var buffer = new char[bufferSize];
            _process.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);

            var text = new StringBuilder();
            int read = 0;
            do
            {
                // to avoid blocking like in method ReadLine or ReadToEnd we must re-implement it
                read = await _process.StandardOutput.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                text.Append(buffer, 0, read);
            } while (read == bufferSize);

            return text
                // remove last new-liner
                .Remove(text.Length - Environment.NewLine.Length, Environment.NewLine.Length)
                .ToString();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _process.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Привет! Спасибо за идею. Я ее обязательно попробую вечером.
Пока реализовано с помощью эвента:

https://github.com/RainManVays/IPCUtilites/blob/master/IpcPmrep/PmrepWorker.cs